# Non parametric to compare 2 interventions with repeated measurements

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, interaction, nonparametric, interpretation

my experiment is a cross-over randomized trial with 2 conditions (A-B), and repeated measures at baseline and 5 follow-up measurements (time).

I hypothesized that 2 physical drills (A-B) would induce different fatigue magnitude. Data were not normally distributed.

I've treated my data as independent groups (group performing A, group performing B), and compared them. No difference was found (conditions) using Mann-Whitney test. However, differences were present over time using Wilcoxon tests.

I'm struggling with interpretations because groups were not significantly different but independently they presented a time effect not necessarily over the same pairs of time measurements. For example, for a given variable, group A had differences between pre-post0min, pre-post5min, pre-post10min, pre-post20min and pre-post 30min. While group B had a difference between pre-post-20min, and pre-post30min only.

- Were the statistical tests right?
- What nonparametric test would enable to test the interaction that
  I would test with the 2-way ANOVA?
- How should I interpret results    of the example above?

Thanks